# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "sucesión" y "progresión"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas

*Sucesión* y *progresión* son términos matemáticos. A mi modo de ver progresión es un caso especial de sucesión. ¿Quién sabe más detalles?

Comment: Reinhard, ayudaría que explicaras por qué a tu modo ver una es un subconjunto del otro, para no reiterar explicaciones en las respuestas. De todos modos, más parece una pregunta matemática que de lengua

Comment: creo que es off-topic...

Comment: no puedo enviar la pregunta a este stack "https://math.stackexchange.com/"

Comment: Creí que sería *secuencia*.

Comment: @aparente001 ambas sucesiones y progresiones son secuencias numéricas, pero se distinguen por diferentes propiedades, también: todas las sucesiones son progresiones, pero no todas las progresiones son sucesiones(al menos no hasta que no se descubra una formula para generarlas)

Comment: @Mike: Soy profesora de matemáticas y te puedo asegurar que lo que has escrito en tu comentario no es correcto.

Comment: @aparente001: Tengo en casa algún libro de matemáticas de la Editorial Limusa y te puedo asegurar que el término "secuencia" no se usa en matemáticas  (aunque en inglés es "sequence") ni siquiera en México.

Answer (score 11):

Una [*sucesión*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Yc72NJZ) es un "conjunto ordenado de términos que cumplen una ley determinada". Es decir, se trata básicamente de una lista ordenada de números.

Una [*progresión*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UJeVFA8) es una "sucesión de números o términos algebraicos entre los cuales hay una ley de formación constante". Lo que quiere decir esta definición es que se llama *progresiones* a ciertos tipos de sucesiones que se pueden definir dando una regla que relaciona cada término con el término siguiente.

En la práctica, nunca se usa la palabra *progresión* de forma aislada, sino que siempre va acompañada de uno de estos tres adjetivos: *aritmética*, *geométrica* o *armónica*. Es decir, a efectos prácticos una progresión es una sucesión que cumple una de estas tres condiciones:

1. La diferencia entre dos términos consecutivos es constante (*progresión aritmética*).
2. El cociente entre dos términos consecutivos es constante (*progresión geométrica*).
3. La sucesión formada por los inversos (el inverso del número *a* es el número 1/*a*) de cada uno de los términos es una progresión aritmética (*progresión armónica*).

Así que, sí: todas las progresiones son sucesiones, pero no todas las sucesiones son progresiones.

> Por ejemplo, `{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...}` **(los números pares)** es una sucesión y, al mismo tiempo, una progresión aritmética porque la diferencia entre dos términos consecutivos siempre es 2.

> Por ejemplo, `{2, 3, 5, 7, ...}` **(los números primos)** es una sucesión, pero no una progresión porque no cumple ninguna de las tres condiciones mencionadas más arriba.

> Por ejemplo, nos podemos inventar una sucesión el término *n*-ésimo de la cual se calcule con la fórmula *n*<sup>2</sup>, es decir, `{0, 1, 4, 9, 16, ...}`: tampoco es una progresión porque no cumple ninguna de las tres condiciones mencionadas más arriba.

Comment: Correcto!, la progresion es una formula que genera números; la sucesion son numeros que cumplen una regla: 

esto significa que la progresión calcula el siguiente numero el el numero "n" en la progresión, mientras que la sucesión pone el  numero a prueba para saber si forma parte de la sucesión

Comment: De hecho, aquí está la misma pregunta hecha en math.SE (que me parece el sitio más apropiado para hacerla, aquí me parece más bien off-topic):   https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3530240/.